# Pagination in Arcgis wfs request

Tags: gis, arcgis, arcgis-server

Is it possible to send WFS request with pagination? I tried with `STARTINDEX` but it's not working. I want to fetch features within a certain limit

Eg: `http://example.com/ArcGIS/services/<mapping service name>/MapServer/WFSServer?VERSION=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=<type name>&STARTINDEX=10&MAXFEATURE=10`

Or: how will I fetch only objectid / featureid with WFS request so that I can send filter with request?

Answer (score 1):

Well to answer your last question first to request an object by featureID use something like:

```
http://example.com/geoserver/wfs?
  service=wfs&
  version=2.0.0&
  request=GetFeature&
  typeName=namespace:featuretype&
  featureID=feature
```

To do the pagination you use something like:

```
http://example.com/geoserver/wfs?
      service=wfs&
      version=2.0.0&
      request=GetFeature&
      typeName=namespace:featuretype&
      startindex=0&
      maxFeatures=10
```

Some notes on this however. I have only tested against Geoserver and I know that in version 2.1.x of geoserver the startindex has no affect on the results. I know it does work in version 2.3.x. If you are using a particular version of Geoserver I would suggest you look it up. I am not sure what is supported in other applications that serve out wfs. You will need to check with them but what I have given above is in accordance with the WFS spec.

One final thing is you may want to add some sorting when doing this. i.e.

```
http://example.com/geoserver/wfs?
          service=wfs&
          version=2.0.0&
          request=GetFeature&
          typeName=namespace:featuretype&
          startindex=0&
          maxFeatures=10&
          sortBy=namespace:field
```

The reason for this is that without sorting when data is updated the data may change between requests meaning you may not see results ect between pages. That is still possible even with sorting, particularly if not sorting on ID or not using an incremental style ID field. However normally sorting on an ID field will ensure consitancy in paging.

As you are using ArcGis some of that may not be relevate to you. I am pretty sure however that the latest versions of Arc Gis support the WFS Spec for the startindex field.

Comment: Thanks Darkcylde. but I am using arcgis 9.3 which did not support Startindex any way I got the alternative solution for this, now I am using REST API which supports similar functionality for get ID

Comment: Well that does happen perhaps ArcGIS 9.x only supports WFS 1.x. A bit like GeoServer 2.1. Hopefully ArcGIS 10.x (I think they are up to 10.2) Supports the whole WFS 2.0 standard.